# Cant get api integer/float data into a python local variable

Tags: python

[image: Error message to block of code] Hello does anyone has an idea why this piece of python code wont work for me.
I am trying to get a piece of api data into a python local variable and it just wont seem to work
.I tried different solutions

```
from urllib import request
import requests
import datetime
#******************************** VARIABLES  *****************************#

SHEET_ENDPOINT = "https://api.sheety.co/c2508c72b1a9443966fca6445ff27747/workoutTracker/workouts"

#******************************** GET SHEETY API  *****************************#

inbound = requests.get(SHEET_ENDPOINT)
RESULT = inbound.json()

drum = []


for exercise in RESULT["workouts"]:
    date = exercise["date"]
    time = exercise["time"]
    exercise = exercise["exercise"]
    duration = exercise["duration"]
    calories = exercise["calories"]
    g = f"Date:{date}\nTime:{time}\nExercise:{name}\nDuration:{duration}\nCalories:{calories}"
    drum.append(g)
for item in drum:
    print(item)
```

Comment: You are overriding *exercise* with *exercise = exercise["exercise"]* so that *excercise* is now a string rather than the dictionary that it used to be

Comment: That is not actually the faulty line, please look at the error image above

Comment: That **is** the faulty line - that's where the override occurs which subsequently affects *duration = exercise["duration"]*. However, you have now edited the question making it irrelevant so you can close it

Comment: `exercise` is a dict, then after you perform `exercise = exercise["exercise"]` exercise is a string. After this line you do `duration = exercise["duration"]`, but a string - `exercise` now - must be indexed with integers, as the error states.

Comment: alright thanks brother the problem was with the override